# How I can set time limit for R code executing by python (rpy2)?

Tags: python, r, timeout, rpy2

I want to stop executing R function called from python (rpy2) after 2 seconds. Here is python code:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(2) # set timeout to 2 seconds

# run R code
result = robjects.r('''
      Sys.sleep(10) 
      return("hello")
   ''')

signal.alarm(0) # disable alarm
```

It doesn't work. I must wait 10 seconds for signal *handler*.

Comment: It may help folks to know exactly _how_ is doesn't work. Error? Simply ignores request to pause for 10 seconds?

Comment: Simply ignores request to pause for 10 sec. Python know nothing about R code execution time, when I execute it 5 times by robjects - signal appears after first, called _handler_ method, but after 10 seconds, not 2. I woud like to kill R code processing after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluation of R code does not release the Python GIL. The only way to get a Python script to monitor the execution time of R code is to have two processes.

You could check the unit test for rpy2 "testInterruptR()", although there are much more elegant ways to implement that in an application. There a SIGINT is sent to an R process running an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you (I cannot click "Vote Up").

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your alarm and then putting the operation you want the timeout on inside of try catch blocks. The alarm should throw a catchable exception. Hope that makes sense, it works for me anyway.